# Regex list/column to comma delimited

Tags: regex, replace

I have a column of data, in this case captured from a website.  I would like to convert this list into a comma separated list using regex either in the terminal or gedit, etc..

My list:

```
Liam
Noah
William
James
Oliver
Benjamin
```

What I want is:

```
Liam, Noah, William, James, Oliver, Benjamin
```

or

```
(Liam, Noah, William, James, Oliver, Benjamin)
```

or similar.

What I have tried is ^([A-Za-z]+)$("$1",) .  I think it finds each name but it is not replacing anything.

It would also be great if something like this worked with numbers as well.  Like,

```
10
20
30
pie
```

to

```
10,20,30,pie
```

Comment: Replace a newline with `,` + space.

Comment: Ok, can you explain more?  I don't know how to implement your advice.

Comment: Added full answer. Have you tested ?

Comment: Yes, I tested and both work great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\n/, /' file
```

## Output:

```
Liam, Noah, William, James, Oliver, Benjamin,
```

Or better:

```
perl -0ne 'my @a = (split /\n/, $_); print join (", ", @a) . "\n"' file
```

## Output:

```
Liam, Noah, William, James, Oliver, Benjamin
```